# How to log all requests and responses for Play Framework 2.5.x?

Tags: playframework-2.5

I want to log requests and responses for my application. I expect they should be present in access.log file. However, my access.log file is empty. I have enables access logging in configuration.
Here is my prod-logger.xml :

```
<configuration>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${user.dir}/web/logs/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>application-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${user.dir}/web/logs/access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n</pattern>
        <!-- this quadruples logging throughput -->
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- additivity=false ensures access log data only goes to the access log -->
<logger name="access" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Well that is only the definition/configuration of the logging. Are you also calling the logger?